# How to get chosen backend name in HAProxy with lua?

Tags: lua, haproxy

I use 2.8 HAProxy with such config for backends:

```
backend proxies
    http-response lua.notify
    server node-0 node-0:8080 check
    server node-1 node-1:8080 check
```

And I have lua action from a script:

```
core.register_action("notify", { "http-res" }, function(txn)
    local be_name = txn.f:be_name()
    core.log(core.info, "Backend name: " .. be_name)
end)
```

This gives me **proxies**, but I need **node-0** or **node-1**, so I should know which backend was chosen for this request. Is it possible?